# MySQL query counting on multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

At the moment, we have 3 queries. In php, we loop over the first, then execute the 2nd multiple times, then which I'd like to have in one single query:

The first query is:

```
SELECT id FROM users
```

Then inside looping over those results, the 2nd is

```
SELECT id AS rid, count(recommendedById) FROM users WHERE id=$id
```

where $id is users.id from the first query.

The 3rd query is which is executed inside the 2nd loop is:

```
SELECT count(likes) AS likeCounter FROM posts WHERE author_id=$rid
```

and likeCounter is summed up to the first query.

Anyone able to bring this into one query?

**Desired result**
The result should be a row per user with a count of users he recommended and a sum of likes his recommended users got on their posts.

Comment: What is the final result?  One value that is the sum?  Or a separate count for each user?

Comment: The result should be a row per user with a count of users he recommended and a sum of likes his recommended users got on their posts. I'll add that above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT u.id,COUNT(DISTINCT ruid),sum(p.likes)
FROM users as u
LEFT JOIN (SELECT recommendedById as rid,id as ruid from users) as r ON r.rid = u.id
LEFT JOIN posts p ON p.author_id = ruid
GROUP BY u.id
```

Comment: you shoud include the users table structure into the question, i was forced to guess it

Comment: I added an another query, that may have a nicer query plan

Comment: In this fiddle author 2 has a post in which he received 30 likes, and author 3 has a post in which he received 1 like, but your query don't show any of this. Instead SUM(p.likes) is accumulating 31 to author 1 that should have 20 likes.

Comment: counting the likes of reccomended users, 1 recommended 2,3 so those likes counts there, 3 recommended none, 2 recommended 4,5 but no post for that users

Comment: *sum of likes his recommended users got on their posts* oh okay I missed this part... kinda weird statistic

Comment: it's not a statistic, it's for a contest - bring users to our site which post content which is liked - and win an iPad :)

Comment: so the first query is better for me, as I need ALL users

Comment: how can I add a WHERE-clause to the 2nd LEFT JOIN on the first query?

Comment: `LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM posts WHERE ...) p ON p.author_id = ruid`

Comment: and I'd also need to add these two up: COUNT(DISTINCT rid),sum(p.likes) - this (COUNT(DISTINCT rid) + sum(p.likes)) does not work?

Comment: thanks for the "where"... should have seen that myself, but I'm really in a hurry...

Comment: Sorry @cske but could you explain on how to also count post.likes to a separate column? I tried: LEFT JOIN (SELECT author_id, likes FROM posts) AS p2 ON p2.author_id = u.id but that did not work, it gives false numbers... thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
SELECT u.id AS rid, count(recs.id), count(p.likes) AS likeCounter
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN posts p ON p.author_id=u.id
LEFT JOIN users recs ON recs.recommendedById=u.id
GROUP BY u.id
```

But a user has an id, and you use `id` from the `users` table. Isn't that always 1?

Comment: what is $id? I'd like to have it as a pure sql-query. Thanks so far!

Comment: Now its for all users, just removed the WHERE statement

Comment: It doesn't work like it should. Likes should be counted on users you recommended, so if your users.id is "32", and users.id 63/67/71 have users.recommendedByUserId "32", the likes on their posts should be summed up and shown on users.id 32

Comment: So more like I got now? A count of recommended users.